# How can I traverse an array with stride?

Tags: swift

I want to traverse an array with a stride. For example, I have an array `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.And I want to traverse this array with a stride of `3`. The `oc` code likes below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i += 3) {

}
```

How can I do that with `swift`.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, what should be your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop with stride to traverse the array

```
let testarray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in stride(from: 0, to: testarray.count, by: 3) {
    print(testarray[i])
}
```